# ImportError: cannot import name 'MapWrapper'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, importerror

I am trying to use the r2_score() for some curve fits. I have scikit-learn verison 0.19.1 installed, and I have tried:
`from sklearn.metrics import *` (or `from sklearn.metrics import r2_score()`), but it gives me the error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-292-c0154f305c6f> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.metrics import *

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py in <module>()
      5 
      6 
----> 7 from .ranking import auc
      8 from .ranking import average_precision_score
      9 from .ranking import coverage_error

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py in <module>()
     24 import numpy as np
     25 from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
---> 26 from scipy.stats import rankdata
     27 
     28 from ..utils import assert_all_finite

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py in <module>()
    386 
    387 """
--> 388 from .stats import *
    389 from .distributions import *
    390 from .morestats import *

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in <module>()
    174 from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
    175 from scipy.ndimage import measurements
--> 176 from scipy._lib._util import (_lazywhere, check_random_state, MapWrapper,
    177                               rng_integers, float_factorial)
    178 import scipy.special as special

ImportError: cannot import name 'MapWrapper'
```

Do you know what that is? Am I still missing something or does it hava to do with some version incompatibilities?
Same exact thing happens when I try to import lmfit, which I had previously installed.

Comment: I think that there might be some problems with multiple mismatched versions of your packages. I would try to uninstall problematic ones and install them again.

Comment: Yes I figured that could be the problem. The question is which ones are the problematic ones..